# What is the technical term for a non slip-on/slip fit bath spout that installs through the wall?

Tags: shower, terminology, spout

I ordered a shower kit online that included a wall mounted tub spout.  When I went to install the tub spout I discovered that it had a very large male thread, some kind of nut, and an adapter (looked like some NTP, tapered thing).  The spout is supposed to be mounted through the wall, and the adapted is tightened into the pipe behind the wall.  I've never seen a spout like this before.  It's definitely not something can work with due to wall access issues.

What is the technical term for this type of spout/spout installation?  (assuming it installs the way I think it does)

[image: Bath Spout]

Answer (score 0):

The spout that you have in hand is meant to be installed to a secure bulkhead such as a tub wall, shower enclosure wall or other wall plate. You would not simply mount this piece onto the end of a shower pipe in the wall.

Comment: So, no technical term for what type of spout that is?  (maybe there isn't one?)

Comment: "Wall mounted" as opposed to "deck mounted" (most common, in the UK at least) or "side mounted" (what you were looking for). I also see taps advertised as "3 hole" (or 4 or 5 hole) to indicate that the handles, bath filler spout, shower wand are separate. Just guessing...